# Deleted accidentaly folder with projects deployed on gcloud datastore

Tags: python, web-deployment, gcloud, datastore

I am a newbie in the dev world and I made a big mistake this morning with my 5 database projects made in python. Basically I accidentally deleted the folder with my templates and my code. All of them are deployed on gcloud datastore, but I was wondering if there is any method to rescue or to have a backup folder with all the files. Thank you so much and I hope there is a solution

Answer (score 0):

After deletion it is not possible to recover Datastore data unless a backup is available. Usually backups are not necessary as data is replicated across multiple data centers.